# redirect_to edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, controller, routes

I have quite a long form in my app so I've set up a `_new_form.html.erb` which is rendered in my `new.html.erb`.  After the user updates this form and passes some basic validations I would like them to be redirected to the `edit.html.erb` which renders the full form, i.e. `_new_form.html.erb`.

I'm sure this is basic stuff but I can't find out how to do it.

I've tried updating the **Create** action in my Contoller with the below but I'm getting now where.

i.e.

```
  def create
    @location = Location.new(params[:location])
      #redirect_to :action => "edit"

    respond_to do |format|
      if @location.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_location_path(:id), notice: 'Location was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @location, status: :created, location: @location }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @location.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're trying to redirect to `edit_location_path(:id)`. The symbol `:id` is not what you want to pass here. You want the location's id or the location itself: `redirect_to edit_location_path(@location)`